# (Windows & Plesk) The directory C:\Windows\Temp\ exists but is not writable

Tags: iis

I'm trying to deploy a site to a Windows VPS (which I am new to) which uses Plesk Web Pro Edition (which I'm also new to). I'm getting the standard error: `The directory C:\Windows\Temp\ exists but is not writable` which I am very used to dealing with when using linux, but not with Windows / Plesk.

Presumably I just need to change the permissions on the temp directory,  but as far as I can tell I'm unable to SSH into the server, and I've tried using the remote connection but access to C:\Windows is denied when I try to make any changes.

Has anyone had any experience with dealing with this?

Comment: Run away as fast as you can. This is just not the right server software for Drupal.
Having said that, since the system requires certain permissions to set the permissions for the temp dir, and you don't have those, you'll have to get those permissions from someone.
Is Drupal running yet on it? If so, you can change the temp directory in the settings to some path you do have permission to.

Comment: Are you able to RDP into the machine? If so, you can change the permission of the IUSR (IIS 7 and up) so that the user is allowed to write in the temp directory. If you cannot RDP into the machine I guess that you should change the permissions inside the Plesk web panel.